# Why am I getting a 404 error on this URL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

Could anyone please tell me why I am getting a `404` error when I type `\book` in the URL?

Here is my code:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    chalk = require('chalk'),
    debug = require('debug')('app'),
    morgan = require('morgan'),
    path = require('path'),
    PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;


app.use(morgan('tiny'));
const bookRoutes = require('./routes/bookroutes');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'/public')));
app.use('/css',express.static(path.join(__dirname,'/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css')))
app.use('/js',express.static(path.join(__dirname,'/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js')))
app.use('/js',express.static(path.join(__dirname,'/node_modules/jquery/dist')))

app.use('book',bookRoutes);
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/views/index.html'))
});


app.listen(PORT, () => {
    debug(`listing to ${chalk.red(PORT)}`);

});
```

And **bookroutes.js**:

```
var express = require('express');
var bookRoutes = express.Router();

bookRoutes.route('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log('book')
    res.send('book')
});

module.exports = bookRoutes;
```

When I enter http://localhost:3000/book in the browser URL, it will show these errors:

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
  app listing to 3000 +0ms
GET /worker.js 404 148 - 7.814 ms
GET /book 404 143 - 1.021 ms
```

Comment: try `app.use('/book',bookRoutes);`

Comment: not working same output

Comment: also need to specify request type in your route controller. it should be `bookRoutes.get('/', ())`;. not `route`.

Comment: but I saw i example it say `route`

Comment: where I will use `route`

Comment: yes, you can but still need to specify request type. see [here](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router.route). You use `route` when your route has a common name but serves different types of requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code. You're missing a `/` in your route definition.

```
app.use('/book', bookRoutes);
```

And inside `bookRoutes.js`, you've to make use of the `get` method on the `router` object to define a handler for `GET /book` endpoint.

```
bookRoutes.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('book');
});
```

For more info, check the [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#router.METHOD).